# django issue cant insert comment from url

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have been following django girls tutorial and I run into comment issue. I can add comment to the post from Admin interface but I cant add it from the form.

Here is my model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):

post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
ctext = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def approve(self):
    self.approved_comment = True
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.ctext
```

Here is my form:

```
    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('ctext',)
```

And a view:

```
    def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
        else:
            form = CommentForm()
            return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})
```

Any advice will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Where is it failing? Are you getting a 404 or form is invalid? What's the form data that you are passing in the request?

Comment: no failing at all... and not log in postgres so it even does not go to db. I have no idea how to debug it. In the form I am passing only the comment text. I assume that userid and postid is somehow should be there.

Comment: Add some print statements to figure out.

Comment: how I do the print statements in django's fw?

Comment: For example, add `print(form)` after you initialize the form.

Comment: <class 'blog.models.Comment.DoesNotExist'> this is all I see in debug but it never gets to print(CommentForm)

Comment: I think you dont need pass the argument `instance` to `CommentForm`.

Comment: here is the form values: I am in add_commnets_to_post
form is valid:
<tr><th><label for="id_ctext">Ctext:</label></th><td><textarea name="ctext" cols="40" rows="10" required id="id_ctext">
new text for comment field</textarea></td></tr> . Do you know where I can see the whole insert query that goes into db. Somewhere it should pic the userid and postid to which  comment is attached.

Comment: OMG! Sachin, thank you so much for this!: "I think you dont need pass the argument instance to CommentForm"!!

Answer (score 0):

Sachin Kukreja in the comments suggested to remove instance=post from Comment form and this solve the issue. Thank you!